# Image not showing in applet

Tags: java, image, applet

I have a small JApplet that is supposed to simply import an image and display it on screen. However, I am having some trouble with it.

```
private Image logo1;

public void init() {
    logo1 = getImage( getCodeBase(), "Penguins.jpg" );
}

@Override
public void paint( Graphics g ) {
    g.drawImage( logo1, 0, 0, this );
}
```

That is essentially my entire program. Is there any problem with it? I am assuming one of the problems might be that the picture might have to be in a specific part of  your computer or something like that...The address for this image is C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures

Comment: It has to be in the codebase. Most likely, this is the folder that holds your `src` folder.

Comment: You never said what the problem is. Is the applet not running or is it running but not displaying the image or what?

Comment: the image isn't showing up. sorry.

Comment: You should never draw directly in the applet's paint method. Instead override a JPanel's paintComponent method, paint the image in the JPanel (or even easier as a JLabel's ImageIcon), add the JPanel to your JApplet and display it. You will want to copy the image and move it so that it is loaded with the applet's jar in its own subdirectory, and then use that path when loading the image.

Comment: @Jon, if you want, you could put that as an answer so I can accept it. That made it work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that `getCodeBase()` is in the method call of `getImage()` is to get the codebase location.

The codebase is the folder that holds all of your source packages. It's most likely the folder  above your `src` folder for your project. Here's the basic structure of a normal project (at least my projects):

> -MyProject          - *This is the codebase*
>    
>   -src                   - *All of your code is probably in this folder. All packages show up as folders here*
>    
>   -bin                   - *When your code compiles, it ends up here*
>    
>   -data                 - *This is where all of the resources are held (my preference)*
>      
>   -images          - *Pretty obvious, the image would go here*
>        
>   -Penguin.jpg - *Your image*

All this leads up to this answer: With the above structure, your call to `getImage()` should read:

```
getImage(getCodeBase(), 'data/images/Penguin.jpg');
```

Comment: In my case, I just supplied the complete path of the image and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try including the image that you want to display in the folder of your java program. Sometimes if the image is in another folder, it's not displayed in the applet. 
I too faced a similar problem. Just copy the image into your project folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void init() {
        Picture =  getImage(getDocumentBase(),"image.gif");
}
```

I use this code. Do following steps to add your image:

1. Clean and Build the project
2. Add the image into build folder of your project.
3. Run the project.